# do I need to put firebase analytics codes in each activity in my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

do I need to put this firebase analytics codes in each activity in my app?
the code is:

`private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;`

`mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);`

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Comment: FirebaseAnalytics enables you to logEvent. So wherever you want to log your event, you need to make FirebaseAnalytics instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics tracks many events automatically when you include the SDK, such as when the app is opened, and [certain types of activities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews). For a list of these see [automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485).

If you want to track more events, you can [log them yourself](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#log_events_2) from your application code.